# Bootstrap row with horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get a row with multiple columns (dynamic with no max) and therefore to get an horizontal scroll.

When i insert a new column that exceeds the size 12 of bootstrap, it takes that column to a new line. 
What I want is to preserve that column in the same line and to get the horizontal scroll view.

Tried already with something like this, but didn't worked...

```
<div class="span11" style="overflow: auto">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">COL1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

row-fluid need the style attribute " white-space: nowrap; " and the divs inside need the style attribute " display: inline-block; "

```
.row-fluid{
     white-space: nowrap;
}
.row-fluid .col-lg-3{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

[try it](http://jsfiddle.net/8mr9ff9b/)

Comment: I added something akin to `.col-lg-3 { white-space: normal; }` to "restore" that property inside the row's "items".

Comment: Thanks! Remember to remove the "row" classname.

Answer (score 8):

Larger screen will also need `float: none;` in `col-` classes.

```
.row-fluid {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.row-fluid .col-lg-3 {
     display: inline-block;
     float: none;
}
```