# Bootstrap Row of Images that Scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a row of divs with background images to scroll horizontally like a Netflix style list I have written this:

http://jsfiddle.net/o3mxb4x9/

CSS:

```
.cover-container
{
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.cover-item
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 8px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #bbb;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    width: 116px;
    height: 158px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But I cannot get it to overflow horizontally and therefore scroll left and right.

I am using Bootstrap 3 for my framework.

I have tried doing this from another stack question but it is not working for me either. ([Bootstrap row with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281242/bootstrap-row-with-horizontal-scroll))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technique works, but you have to do that on your container:

```
.cover-container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

And, remove `float` from your items:

```
.cover-item {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o3mxb4x9/1/

.